# SQL query slow with OR but very fast with UNION in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem where i want to add an OR to a query, but this makes it run very slowly. 
the query looks something like this:

```
SELECT TRIM(l.ID) ID,
       TRIM(C.UID) UID,
       TRIM(c.UPLOADED_ID) UPLOADED_ID,
       TRIM(l.record_key) record_key,
       TRIM(c.customers_record_key) customers_record_key,
       c.prohibitautoupdate,
       TRIM(c.c_additional_key) c_additional_key,
       TRIM(c.record_status) c_record_status    
FROM tmp_customers_upload l, customers c

WHERE (l.record_key = c.customers_record_key AND NVL(TRIM(l.ID),' ') <> c.UPLOADED_ID AND c.UPLOADED_ID IS NOT NULL )
OR (SUBSTR(C.UID, 6, 11) = TRIM(L.ID) AND (L.record_key<> C.UPLOADED_ID OR C.UPLOADED_ID IS NULL) AND (C.UPLOADED_ID <> L.ID OR C.UPLOADED_ID IS NULL))
       and c.record_status <> 'DL'
       and c.prohibitautoupdate = 0;
```

This query is a simplified version of what i want to run, and it takes forever to run (more than 3 minutes which is unacceptable)

now when i run this:

```
 SELECT TRIM(l.ID) ID,
       TRIM(C.UID) UID,
       TRIM(c.UPLOADED_ID) UPLOADED_ID,
       TRIM(l.record_key) record_key,
       TRIM(c.customers_record_key) customers_record_key,
       c.prohibitautoupdate,
       TRIM(c.c_additional_key) c_additional_key,
       TRIM(c.record_status) c_record_status    
FROM tmp_customers_upload l, customers c 
WHERE (l.record_key = c.customers_record_key AND NVL(TRIM(l.ID),' ') <> c.UPLOADED_ID AND c.UPLOADED_ID IS NOT NULL )
   and c.record_status <> 'DL'
   and c.prohibitautoupdate = 0;

UNION SELECT TRIM(l.ID) ID,
       TRIM(C.UID) UID,
       TRIM(c.UPLOADED_ID) UPLOADED_ID,
       TRIM(l.record_key) record_key,
       TRIM(c.customers_record_key) customers_record_key,
       c.prohibitautoupdate,
       TRIM(c.c_additional_key) c_additional_key,
       TRIM(c.record_status) c_record_status    
FROM tmp_customers_upload l, customers c
WHERE (SUBSTR(C.UID, 6, 11) = TRIM(L.ID) AND (L.record_key <> C.customers_record_key OR C.customers_record_key IS NULL) AND (C.UPLOADED_ID <> L.ID OR C.UPLOADED_ID IS NULL))
    and c.record_status <> 'DL'
    and c.prohibitautoupdate = 0;
```

It takes less than a second to run.

As far as I understand, the first version does an implicit JOIN and the WHERE clause is acting like ON, and the OR somehow confuses the DB which makes it do a full table scan.

my question is how to optimize the query to make it run fast? i prefer not to use the union because as i said, this is only a simplified version of the query which actually has more than 30 columns, so using the union will greatly reduce readability and maintainability of the SP which contains these queries(which are actually CURSORS in the SP)

any help will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Please perform this on sqlprompt, connecting to same database : set lines 999 set pages 999 set autotrace traceonly explain <execute query with OR clause > Above will give you explain plan used by query. Post plan here. We can look at plan to know hitting area of slow query. - Abhi

Comment: But Abhi, we already know why the query is slow -- I explained in my answer.

Comment: Hi, your 1st query has an uneven set of parenthesis in the where clause.  Can you fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are not using modern style joins you can't see that your join conditions are totally different.

Since your join conditions are totally different when you try and make it into one query you actually cause the join conditions to morph into a CROSS JOIN (look it up) so you end up with the multiple of the two tables and no ability to use indexes.

If I had to unwind this I would first switch to modern style joins so it clear exactly how you are joining -- then it will be clear if you have a logic problem -- I think you do.  If the logic problem is removed then it will probably be trivial to combine the queries.

Or not -- if the logic does not allow it to be combined (because they join different) and you have to use a union.

In that case it is probably best to create a view or a CTE that is shared by both the queries to ease the maintenance issues.

Comment: thanks, but what do you mean modern joins? explicit joins?

Comment: @monkeyStix -- joins made with the `JOIN` keyword are called modern joins because they were added to the SQL standard most recently.